I want to count the number of files in a folder, but it only shows the number of subfolders
I want to count the number of files in a folder. But even though there are some files in the folder, it shows me the number zero. Interestingly, it only shows the number of available subfolders!!!!!!
It should be noted that there are 5 normal files with *.jpg extensions in the folder that can be viewed by the file manager.
    myfolder = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/RubikaDownloaders";

    // ...

    public int getFilesCount(String folder) {
    File directory = new File(folder);
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    if (files == null)
        return 0;
    for (File file : files)
        Log.i("mytag", "name=" + file.getName());
    return files.length;
}


Does this answer your question? Why File.listFiles() method can only list directories

This code solved my problem. Thanks dear @teapot418.
if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
//todo when permission is granted
} else {
//request for the permission
Intent intent = new 
Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
}

